# I forgot what this is called?

Tags: c++, namespaces, scope

Ok so I have this code and I KNOW it's not good programming practice. I just forgot what it's called.

```
int main()
{
    int variable; 
    {
        int variable;
    }
}
```

Is that a local namespace or something? I just can't remember the correct term for doing something such as that.

Comment: It's just an inner block of code.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing

Comment: @FatalError +1 for how your comment (link + sig) reads :)

Answer (score 8):

The `{ ... }` is a *block* or *compound statement*, which creates a nested *scope*. (It's not a `namespace`.)

This particular case, of a declaration in an inner scope having the same name as (and therefore hiding) a declaration in an outer scope is sometimes called *shadowing*.

g++ can warn about this. Quoting [the manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/Warning-Options.html):

```
`-Wshadow'
     Warn whenever a local variable or type declaration shadows another
     variable, parameter, type, or class member (in C++), or whenever a
     built-in function is shadowed. Note that in C++, the compiler will
     not warn if a local variable shadows a struct/class/enum, but will
     warn if it shadows an explicit typedef.
```

(As Adam Rosenfield points out in a comment, `-Wshadow` is not enabled by `-Wall`, `-Wextra`, or `-pedantic`; you have to enable it explicitly.)

Comment: Note that `-Wshadow` is not enabled by any of `-Wall`, `-Wextra`, or `-pedantic`, so it must be manually added as a command-line option; that's likely because it may generate lots of false positives for perfectly fine code.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're referring to is variable hiding, or variable shadowing. By declaring a variable in the inner scope with the same name as the outer scope, you are hiding the outer variable from the inner scope. Obviously in more complicated code this could be confusing.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing

Comment: You can only do that if the other variable is in the global namespace.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Really? So you claim that `namespace Foo { int i; void Bar() { int i; } }` is impossible?

Comment: MSalters; no, the answer has been edited since then. answerer was saying something about using ::.

Answer (score 2):

You are *shadowing* an existing variable. This is not good programming practice.

Out of interest, Java forbids it.

Answer (score 0):

I would call it a scope. I think that's what others call it too.

Answer (score 0):

There is two concepts going on here, one you are creating a `block scope` within the `{ ... }` and you are hiding the outer instance of `variable` within this block scope. A block scope is being created by a compound statement(*or block*), if we look at the C++ draft standard section `6.3` *Compound statement or block* paragraph *1* has the following grammar:

```
compound-statement:
  { statement-seqopt}
```

it also says:

> A compound statement defines a block scope (3.3).

and if we look at section `3.3.3`  *3.3.3 Block scope* paragraph *1* says:

> A name declared in a block (6.3) is local to that block; it has block scope. Its potential scope begins at its point of declaration (3.3.2) and ends at the end of its block. A variable declared at block scope is a local variable.

So what is happening with `variable` is that the local copy in the inner block is `hiding` the instance of `variable` in the outer block since it has the same name.

Answer (score 0):

it is simply called scope of a variable.c permits us to define samevariable name variables .